# How can I optimize my flow control when looping through an array to find a matching value in another array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, while-loop

I think i'm like 99% of the way there on this problem, but for some reason I'm having a really tough time wrapping my head around the right control flow in the last several lines of my sub routine.

To get a sense of what i'm hoping my script will accomplish, please feel welcome to take a look at the attached image, as it might be easier to understand when looking at a visual.

[image: Subroutine Visualized]

Essentially I need to loop through each element in the target array, see if matches the corresponding element of the search array, and if that's true, then I need to find the closest number in the search array. Lastly, I need the name and closest matching number in a new match array. I need to work with arrays because my data set might eventually extend to thousands of rows.

Below is my code. I'm struggling with my While Loop. For reasons unknown to me, it just loops indefinitely until I get a runtime error. Can anyone help me wrap my head around why this isn't working  or tell me if there's a more efficient way to do this?

```
Sub match_tables()

'create target array and populate with values from range columns

Dim upboundlengthtarget As Long, targetarr As Variant
upboundlengthtarget = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count - 1
ReDim targetarr(2, 0 To upboundlengthtarget) As Variant

Dim target_name_range As Range, target_name_cell As Range, tnmcol As Long
Set target_name_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each target_name_cell In target_name_range
    targetarr(1, tnmcol) = target_name_cell
    tnmcol = tnmcol + 1
Next target_name_cell

Dim target_num_range As Range, target_num_cell As Range, tnbrcol As Long
Set target_num_range = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each target_num_cell In target_num_range
    targetarr(2, tnbrcol) = target_num_cell
    tnbrcol = tnbrcol + 1
Next target_num_cell

'create search array and populate with values from range columns

Dim upboundlengthsearch As Long, searcharr As Variant
upboundlengthsearch = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count - 1
ReDim searcharr(2, 0 To upboundlengthsearch) As Variant

Dim search_name_range As Range, search_name_cell As Range, snmcol As Long
Set search_name_range = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each search_name_cell In search_name_range
    searcharr(1, snmcol) = search_name_cell
    snmcol = snmcol + 1
Next search_name_cell

Dim search_num_range As Range, search_num_cell As Range, snbrcol As Long
Set search_num_range = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each search_num_cell In search_num_range
    searcharr(2, snbrcol) = search_num_cell.Value
    snbrcol = snbrcol + 1
Next search_num_cell

'create match array with same dimensions as target array

Dim matchupboundlength As Long, matcharr As Variant
matchupboundlength = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count - 1
ReDim matcharr(2, 0 To matchupboundlength) As Variant

'populate match array with matching name and closest number

Dim match As Boolean, maxsrchnum As Long, result As Long, index As Long
maxsrchnum = Application.Max(srcharr, 2)
For p = LBound(targetarr, 2) To UBound(targetarr, 2)
    For q = LBound(searcharr, 2) To UBound(searcharr, 2)
        If targetarr(1, p) = searcharr(1, q) Then
        match = True
        Else
        match = False
        q = q + 1
        End If
            Do While match = True
                If Abs(targetarr(2, p) - searcharr(2, q)) < maxsrchnum Then
                    maxsrchnum = Abs(targetarr(2, p) - searcharr(2, q))
                    matcharr(2, index) = searcharr(2, q)
                    matcharr(1, index) = searcharr(1, q)
                    index = index + 1
                End If
            Loop
    Next q
    p = p + 1
Next p

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by with less code:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim arrTarget, arrSearch, arrMatch, ws As Worksheet, minDiff, diff, v
    Dim i As Long, m As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'target data
    arrTarget = ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    'size output array
    ReDim arrMatch(1 To UBound(arrTarget, 1), 1 To UBound(arrTarget, 2))
    'search data
    arrSearch = ws.Range("C2:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrTarget, 1)
        minDiff = -1 'reset this
        For m = 1 To UBound(arrSearch, 1)
            If arrSearch(m, 1) = arrTarget(i, 1) Then
                diff = Abs(arrSearch(m, 2) - arrTarget(i, 2))
                If diff < minDiff Or minDiff = -1 Then
                    minDiff = diff
                    v = arrSearch(m, 2)
                    If minDiff = 0 Then Exit For 'exact match
                End If
            End If
        Next m
        arrMatch(i, 1) = arrTarget(i, 1)
        If minDiff <> -1 Then arrMatch(i, 2) = v 'best match
    Next i
    
    'populate the results on the sheet
    ws.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrMatch, 1), UBound(arrMatch, 2)).Value = arrMatch

End Sub
```